# Double COUNT in one query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, pivot

I would like to do those both COUNT in one query, which is the best way?
I want to count both sales and both leads based on status_id

```
SELECT COUNT(status_id) as Leads FROM activities WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) AND status_id =5
SELECT COUNT(status_id) as Sales FROM activities WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) AND status_id =4
```

Comment: For performance, to allow a range scan operation on column `date` (with suitable index  available), we avoid wrapping the column in a function. We can reference the bare column in the condition, and compare that to expressions that derive the first day of this week and first day of next week, e.g. `WHERE activities.date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW(),1),'-1'),'%x%v-%w') AND activities.date < STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW(),1),'-1'),'%x%v-%w') + INTERVAL 1 WEEK`

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you'll want to be able to tell the two apart, so add `status_id` to your `SELECT` list, then `GROUP` on it.

```
SELECT status_id, COUNT(status_id) as Leads 
FROM activities 
WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) 
AND status_id IN (4,5)
GROUP BY status_id;
```

*Edit based on comments:*

> I want one count to select status_id as Leads and the other one as Sales.

You're actually looking for conditional aggregation, then. Sample data and desired results in your question would've made this clearer from the outset.

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Leads,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status_id = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sales
FROM activities 
WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) 
AND status_id IN (4,5)
GROUP BY status_id;
```

Comment: I want one count to select status_id as Leads and the other one as Sales.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Count use sum Like this

For more explanation.
A COUNT **without** Group  BY gives always the result of all rows in my example 5 for both SELECT Count (status_id = 5), Count (status_id = 4).

As i don't use a GROUP BY in my correct answer, SUM is the only solution

> ```
> CREATE TaBLE activities
> (status_id Integer,
> `date` Date
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO activities
> VALUES (4,now()),(4,now()),(4,now()),(5,now()),(5,now());
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT SUM(IF(status_id= 5,1,0)) as Leads , SUM(IF(status_id= 4,1,0)) as SALES 
> FROM activities 
> WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> Leads | SALES
> ----: | ----:
>     2 |     3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bf95b6164d82ccb791b2b4b61c7f508b)*

Comment: Why use sum over count?

Comment: Count (status_id = 5) = Count (status_id = 4) = 5 and that is not the answer you are looking for

Comment: @martin - SUM requires two fewer key strokes than COUNT and can sometimes be easier to read by being more explicit *(COUNT would rely on returning `NULL` instead of `0` and people confuse themselves with NULLs.)*.

Comment: @MatBailie thanks, I was making a quick effort to get nbk to **edit** and update his answer so as to make it more useful as a code only answer and actually teach the OP *why* this is the best solution. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT status_id, CASE when status_id = 5 then 'Leads' else 'Sales' end as ColName,
COUNT(status_id) as ColCount
FROM activities
WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
  AND status_id in (5, 4)
group by status_id
```

Comment: You should also select `status_id`. Otherwise you don't know which row belogs to which `status_id`.

Comment: You need count in 2 columns? Can you share the expected result?

Comment: I want to count both sales and both leads based on status_id

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT status_id,
       SUM(Case when Status_id=5 then 1 else 0 end) as Leads,
       SUM(Case when Status_id=4 then 1 else 0 end) as Sales
FROM activities 
WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) 
      AND status_id IN (4,5)
GROUP BY status_id;
```

This will give you tow fields with leads and sales values. Hope this helps.